How to block pop-up, banner ads and video ads in iframe in Next.js?
I am embedding a video player that has popup banner ads. When looking for ways to block them, I first found sandbox attribute but the site embed site didn't allow me to use sandbox attribute. Then I came across another solution, which worked perfectly fine with HTML and JS but when I tried doing the same in Next, it didn't work.
This was the solution that worked. Here is the code:
//JS
window.onload = function() {
  var button = document.getElementsByName("sandbox")[0]
  var iframe = document.getElementsByName("framez")[0] button.addEventListener('click', sndbx, false);

  function sndbx() {
    var nibba = document.getElementById("framez").src;
    if (iframe.sandbox == 'allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-    navigation') {
      document.getElementById("framez").removeAttribute("sandbox");
    }
    frames['framez'].location.href = nibba;
    iframe.sandbox = 'allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-    navigation';
  }
}

<button name="sandbox">
  SandBox
</button>
<iframe name="framez" id="framez" src="YOUR_SOURCE" allowfullscreen="true">
</iframe>

And this is how I changed to make it work for Next.js:
"use client";
import React,
{
  useRef
}
from 'react';

const IframeComponent = () = >{
  const iframeRef = useRef(null);

  const handleClick = () = >{
    const iframe = iframeRef.current;
    const iframeSrc = iframe.src;

    if (iframe.sandbox === 'allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation') {
      iframe.removeAttribute('sandbox');
    }

    iframe.contentWindow.location.href = iframeSrc;
    iframe.sandbox = 'allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation';
  };

  return ( < div > <iframe ref = {
    iframeRef
  }
  id = "framez"name = "framez"src = "SOURCE GOES HERE"width = "100%"height = "500px"allowFullScreen allow = "encrypted-media" > </iframe>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Change Iframe Source</button > </div>
  );
};

export default IframeComponent;


But it doesn't seem to work, how do I fix it?
